# What is the word that describes willingness of a human or even an animal to provide value to others in general?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, abstract-nouns, concept

For example, willingness to provide for someone is generosity and willingness to protect someone is bravery, but if we wanted to put both of these (an possibly other values) under an umbrella term, what would that word be?

Comment: 'Willingness to protect someone'; is not the primary meaning of _bravery_.

Comment: You've given this the [single-word-requests] tag but do not appear to have followed [the guidelines for those questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please [edit] your question with the requested information as existing answers (including mine!) may not actually be what you need.

Answer (score 2):

[***Altruism***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/altruism) appears to fit:

> *uncountable noun*
> Altruism is unselfish concern for other people's happiness and welfare.
> Synonyms: *selflessness, charity, consideration, goodwill*
>
> — Collins

> 1. the principle or practice of unselfish concern for the welfare of others
> 2. the philosophical doctrine that right action is that which produces the greatest benefit to others
>
> — *ibid.*

Answer (score 0):

If you provide for someone, then you are kind to them; similarly, if you protect them, it is often out of kindness, or that's what it amounts to anyway, kindness. As well, if you favour people with special advantages, which means that you make available to them certain opportunities of value, or, in the words of the OP, if you "provide value" to them, then, again, this is done out of kindness. So it seems to me that "*kindness*" is an umbrella term, at least a basic one.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/kind_2))
>
> **kind** adjective
> (comparative kinder, superlative kindest)
> caring about others; gentle, friendly and generous
>
> • a very kind and helpful person

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/kindness?q=kindness))
>
> **kindness** noun  ​[uncountable]
> the quality of being kind
>
> • to treat somebody with kindness and consideration